# Can't create files with specific names in specific directories. "no space left on device"

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, search-indexing

I ran into problems with a proces that produces a huge amount of files within a subdirectory (potentially even going into the millions) following a very specific filename-scheme (e.g. something like this : "GC000245325.faa_vs_GC00030243234.faa.diamond").

The names are all unique but all follow that specific naming scheme.

suddenly now the process fails when it needs to create a very specific filename of that scheme, returning "no space left on device". also, I get the same error when trying to create a file of that specific name in that directoy using ```` ´touch``` or ````´mv``´.

I checked that the available number of inodes on the filesystem is NOT used up. Also current documentations state that there are no longer any limits to the number of files within a single directory other than the total number of inodes available on that filesystem.
Also, most strangely, I can create any other file of any other name in that directoy. Just not very this very specific filename.

This suggested to me that this might be some kind of hashing problem, and some research led me to [this blog entry](https://blog.merovius.de/2013/10/20/ext4-mysterious-no-space-left-on.html), which suggested either turning off dir_index or swithing it to another hash-system. Since it then said that switching to another hash_system did not help in his case, i opted for turning it off (figuring that the downside is probably just longer times for file searches...)

SO now the filesystem is generally still intact BUT now, in that specific directory (and ONLY that directory), i can't create ANY file anymore. Now i get the Error Message `Structure needs cleaning`.

Now googling THAT i only get hits suggesting that the filesystem is broken, which it isn't. also turning dirindex back on removes this problem, but then i still can't create that specific filename in that specific subdirectory.

What is happening here? Any suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated...

---

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the missing info: The OS is ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS; The file system in use is EXT4

output of df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs            26G  2.9M   26G   1% /run
/dev/sda3       1.8T  218G  1.5T  14% /
tmpfs           126G     0  126G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/docker/384
/dev/sda1       696M  6.1M  690M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1        44T   22T   20T  53% /home
tmpfs            26G   12K   26G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0      121M  121M     0 100% /snap/docker/423
tmpfs            26G  4.0K   26G   1% /run/user/118
/dev/loop2       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/loop5       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
```

Comment: What filesystem are you actually using? If the limits were removed for ext4, that does not apply to ext2/ext3... And AFAIK if you turn off dir_index you basically get the ext2 behavior, with its original limits.

Comment: OS type? Filesystem type? Output of df -h?

Comment: sorry for the missing info: the filesystem is ext4.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same problem.
Ubuntu 20.04, ext4, LVM.
Error persists past a reboot.

A process is failing to create a specific file in a specific place (but other files can be created, even in that same dir, just not that one specific filename).
I can create the file in a parent dir, but an attempt move it into place throws the same error.

Tried:

- Searching for process holding the file open (nothing, though I can't imagine how anything could be doing this)
- fsck
- e2fsck -apfd (repair, force repair, etc)

This is most probably a filesystem error. I ended up moving the directory aside, creating a new directory, creating the file in there and renaming the directory to the old name.

Mystery not solved, just worked around. Posting here in case my additional clues help some future sleuth.